# How to get string on .values() to foreign key?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I would like to get all positions associated with a particular job post. `JobPost` is an FK to `Position`, and when I do normal `.values()`, I get the foreign key id rather than the position as a string. For example:

```
>>> JobPost.objects.filter(production=p).values('position')
[{'position': 4L}]
```

What I really need to get would be something like, in pseudocode:

```
>>> JobPost.objects.filter(production=p).values('position.position')
```

And the models:

```
class JobPost(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position)

class Position(models.Model):
    position = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JobPost.objects.filter(production=p).values('position__position')`

See [field lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).